# I've Got to add a new record to my access DBMS through VS2008 and ADO.NET how?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ado.net, ms-access-2007, newrow

This is my code:

```
Imports System.Data
Public Class frmNieuweGebruiker

Private Sub frmNieuweGebruiker_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'verbinding maken met databank
    Dim strConnection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=I:\Geïntegreerde proef\ApplicatieOntwikkeling\GIP.mdb"
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM GEBRUIKER"
    Dim dataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, strConnection)
    'databank gebruiker info ophalen.
    dataAdapter.Fill(frmAanmeldingsscherm.dtGEBRUIKER)
    dataAdapter.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub btnGebruikersnaamBevestigen_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGebruikersnaamBevestigen.Click
    Dim strGebruikersnaam As String
    Dim strWachtwoord As String
    Dim drNieuweGebruiker As DataRow = frmAanmeldingsscherm.dtGEBRUIKER.NewRow()

    strGebruikersnaam = txtGebruikersnaam.Text

    If txtWachtwoord.Text <> txtWachtwoordBevestigen.Text Or txtWachtwoord.Text = "" Or txtWachtwoordBevestigen.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("U hebt een fout ingegeven." + vbNewLine + "Probeer nogmaals.")
        txtWachtwoord.Text = ""
        txtWachtwoordBevestigen.Text = ""
    Else
        strWachtwoord = txtWachtwoord.Text

        drNieuweGebruiker("Gebruikersnaam") = strGebruikersnaam
        drNieuweGebruiker("Wachtwoord") = strWachtwoord

        frmAanmeldingsscherm.dtGEBRUIKER.Rows.Add(drNieuweGebruiker)

        frmMenu.Show()
        frmAanmeldingsscherm.txtGebruikersnaam.Text = strGebruikersnaam
        Me.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

He gives a fault report when i tell him to do this:

```
drNieuweGebruiker("Gebruikersnaam") = strGebruikersnaam
drNieuweGebruiker("Wachtwoord") = strWachtwoord
frmAanmeldingsscherm.dtGEBRUIKER.Rows.Add(drNieuweGebruiker)
```

and i just need to add a user to my database...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ensure **Gebruikersnaam** and **Wachtwoord** exist as DataColumns in the dtGEBRUIKER table.

When you say that you get an error on these lines:

```
drNieuweGebruiker("Gebruikersnaam") = strGebruikersnaam 
drNieuweGebruiker("Wachtwoord") = strWachtwoord
frmAanmeldingsscherm.dtGEBRUIKER.Rows.Add(drNieuweGebruiker)
```

Which line? And what error?